# Problem with Blender model imported to Unity (Lighting problems)

Tags: unity, lighting, blender

I made a simple box in blender and imported it to unity. Now I'm facing with this weird lighting problem:

[image: Unity Blender Box]
[image: Blender Box]

I've been messing around with normals, duplicated vertex, lots of things, even lightning properties but still I'm not getting any results at all. Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

Source blend file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ze1JBRFBvhnnY-w36U2KDe7Q2zcfXsmf

Comment: Looks like there's two disjointed meshes (a cube and a cage), so it shows on the shadow. Should it look different?

Comment: yes, I'm gonna edit the question to show you the blender model

Comment: The right face doesn't have that cyan highlight. It wasn't selected, or it "fell through" the cage? Can you share the source blender file?

Comment: I think it's about smoothing I don't really know, I'll share it when I get home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a problem with the mesh, it's a problem with your Unity light settings. Adjust the settings "Bias" and "Normal bias" on your light until the shadow seams go away.